# Change first section of value in dataframe with another value

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I'm attempting to replace the first section of a value in my dataframe by using a lambda function.

Goal:

- If the **Preferred_Name** column is not null then replace everything after the "," in **Resource_Name** with the value listed in **Preferred_Name**.
- If **Preferred_Name** is blank ignore the row.
- Once completed, drop the **Preferred_Name** column.

I wrote this code thus far. I receive an error saying "TypeError: string indices must be integers" which I believe is coming from the `loc.` function.

```
df['Resource_Name'] = df['Resource_Name'].apply(
                                                lambda x: x.split()[2] + ", " + x['Preferred_Name']
                                                if x['Preferred_Name'] == pd.isnull(df.loc[x, 'Preferred_Name'])
                                                else x['Resource_Name']
                                            )
df = df.drop(['Preferred_Name'], axis = 1)
```

**Visual illustration:**

Current display:
[image]

Objective display:

[image]

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[~df['Preferred_Name'].isna(), 'Resource_Name'] = \
    df[~df['Preferred_Name'].isna()]['Resource_Name'].str.extract('(.*,)').squeeze() + ' ' + df['Preferred_Name']

df.drop('Preferred_Name', axis=1)

      Resource_Name
0     Lewis, Calvin
1     Lewis, Calvin
2  Lewis, William C
3     Lewis, Calvin
4     Lewis, Calvin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.str.split()` to split on the comma, take the first part, and then add on the values from `Prefered_Name`, where `Prefered_Name` is not an empty string:

```
new_data = df['Resource_Name'].str.split(r',\s+').str[0] + ', ' + df['Prefered_Name']
df.loc[df['Prefered_Name'] != '', 'Resource_Name'] = new_data
df = df.drop('Prefered_Name', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
Resource_name
0     Lewis, Calvin
1     Lewis, Calvin
2  Lewis, William C
3     Lewis, Calvin
4     Lewis, Calvin
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I came to the conclusion

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'Resource_Name' : ['Will, Turner C', 'Will, William', 'Will, Williamson', 'Will, Will iam son'],
    'Prefered_Name' : [None, 'Bill', None, 'Billy']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
condition_list = [df['Prefered_Name'].values != None]
choice_list = [df['Resource_Name'].apply(lambda x : x.split(',')[0]) + ', ' + df['Prefered_Name']]
df['Resource_Name'] = np.select(condition_list, choice_list, df['Resource_Name'])
df = df[['Resource_Name']]
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
df['Resource_Name'] = df[['Resource_Name', 'Preferred_Name']].apply(
    lambda x: f'{x[0].split(",")[0]}, {x[1]}' if x[1] else x[0], axis=1
)
df.drop('Preferred_Name', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      Resource_Name
0     Lewis, Calvin
1     Lewis, Calvin
2  Lewis, William C
3     Lewis, Calvin
4     Lewis, Calvin
```